# How can I treat implicit function declarations as errors with CMake?

Tags: c, cmake, warnings

I get a warning like below:

```
[build] ../mycode.c: In function ‘time_start’:
[build] ../mycode.c:48:21: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gettimeofday’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
[build]  void time_start() { gettimeofday(&tv1, &timezone); }
[build]                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I suspect I don't have headers for these functions at all. I would like to convert them to errors. How can I do this with CMake?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any compiler-agnostic way to do this with CMake. The compiler needs to support a specific flag (which, if supported, may even be different for different compilers).

In the case of GCC and Clang, you can just add `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` to your compiler flags. With CMake it should be:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "... -Werror=implicit-function-declaration")
```

Where `...` stands for "the rest of your flags".

Useful links:

- [GCC documentation for `-Werror=`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)
- [CMake documentation for `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html)

Comment: Though of course this works only where the selected compiler is one that recognizes that particular option.  GCC is pretty popular, and some other toolchains recognize most of its options, but this issue cannot be addressed generically with CMake.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you're right. Noted at the top of my answer.